# How do I write to a pg database on heroku from ruby? (Not Rails)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a pretty simple ruby file that runs fine on my localhost in the development environment, but I cannot get it to connect to the postgresql database on Heroku.

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG.connect(dbname: 'postgres://uullzzubseknqp:fe8af8be794708c6559d1b521aa285a9500c8645d543fdf23f83bbe7dd628462@ec2-54-235-204-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d80u9t8om01fml')
```

I get this error:

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg.rb:45:in
>   `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   (PG::ConnectionBad) Is the server running locally and accepting from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg.rb:45:in`new'
>   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I can't figure out how to access the DATABASE_URL ENV config variable from Heroku. I've even tried cutting and pasting the actual string into the code in place of the XXXXX and it throws the same error.

I see a ton of advice on StackOverflow on how to do this in a rails app, but none on how to do this as a standalone ruby worker.

Thanks!

Edit: Added the actual DB info to the post. I know it's unsafe, but there is nothing sensitive there, and I will just change it once I have this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

[Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) is a great way to connect and send queries to a DB when not using Rails.

From the doc :

```
DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://user:password@host:port/database_name') # requires pg
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm able to connect to the DB on my localhost already. I'm not really understanding how to do it in the heroku environment specifically.

Comment: Do you know how the DATABASE_URL looks like on your Heroku?

Comment: Yes. actually tried the PG connect with the cut and pasted DATABASE_URL string in there and got the same error. I added it to the original post so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is made up of the user name, password, host, port, and database name, but you are passing the entire string to PG.connect as "dbname".

I suspect that you would pass that string in using a different parameter name (uri?), or break it up into the separate components listed [here](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/0c60865f718e3f003ea876bf6d0ed75ea2ed0056/lib/pg/connection.rb?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) on line 73

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Just so I understand - why would passing in a parameter name or components be any different than passing in the full string?

Comment: Just different ways of doing the same thing. You can take a URL and parse it into the components, or allow those components to be provided separately.